# Do we need to create annotation and configuration files while creating a spring boot library?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm implementing a library using spring boot maven. I'm following a resource that is ["How to Write a Spring Boot Library Project?"](https://medium.com/trendyol-tech/how-to-write-a-spring-boot-library-project-7064e831b63b). In this he created annotation and configuration files. My question is why do we need to create annotation and configuration files, are these necessary while creating any library?

the configuration file that he has created is

```
@EnableFeignClients(clients = RandomJokeClient.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = MarvelousApiClientProxy.class)
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:marvelousapiclient-application.yaml", factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class)
public class MarvelousApiClientConfiguration {
}
```

and annotation file for the above configuration file is

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(MarvelousApiClientConfiguration.class)
public @interface EnableMarvelousApiClient {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question: no, it is not necessary while creating any library. The configuration class here is created to enable component scanning, add a property source and enable component scanning for interfaces that declare they are Feign clients. And the annotation is created in order to conveniently import this configuration into your project.